# Can't convert from a BYTE buffer to a cv::Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, type-conversion, buffer

So i have a problem with converting a BYTE buffer to an image, (cv::Mat).
I am trying to read a real time video from a distant camera, and i got two elements, a pointer to the buffer and the buffer size, and i need to convert that to a cv::Mat image so that i can show it with cv::imshow. i tried to use:

```
cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(bufferSize,CV_8UC3,*buffer),cv::imread_color);
```

but it isn't working and i get this error:

```
 error: (-215:Assertion failed) buf.checkVector(1, CV_8U) > 0 in function 'imdecode_'
```

when i try to convert directly without the imdecode function like this:

```
cv::Mat(bufferSize,CV_8UC3,*buffer)
```

i get an image but i can't show it so the programm just continue running without doing anything.

Can anyone help me please on how do we convert from BYTE buffer pointer to an cv::Mat image

EDIT:

Buffer is declared like this : BYTE *Buffer
the function where i get the buffer from is declared like this

```
void CALLBACK RealDataCallBackEx(LLONG lRealHandle, DWORD dwDataType, BYTE *pBuffer,DWORD dwBufSize, LONG param, LDWORD dwUser)
```

where:
lRealHandle : Real-time monitoring handle
dwDataType  :

```
          0 : Original data which is consistent with data saved  by savedRealData

          1 : Frame data.

          2 : Yuv data.

          3 : Pcm audio data.
```

pBuffer : Buffer for callback data. Data of different length will be called back according to different data type. The data are called back by frame for every type but type 0, and each time one frame is called back.

dwBufSize : Callback data length. The data buffers are diffreent for different types. The unit is BYTE

In my case i always get data type 0
This is how i try to decode then :

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(dwBufSize,CV_8UC3,*pBuffer),cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::Imshow("img",img);
```

my programm stops here, it continue running but it dosen't do anything after cuz i have put a std::cout here to check if it will pass this line of imshow or not but nothing happens

Thank you.

Comment: What is `buffer`? Is it `BYTE**`?

Comment: it's BYTE type pointer variable so it's BYTE*

Comment: What does the buffer contain? Raw pixel data, or the contents of an image file encoded with some specific format (i.e. PNG, JPEG, ...)? In the former case, `imdecode` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Miki `CV_8UC3` seems a bit odd for the input buffer to `imdecode`...

Comment: What does "i get an image but i can't show it so the programm just continue" exactly mean? Provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: @DanMašek The buffer contain Hybrid data which is all i know about the buffer, i am trying to use dahua sdk and they didn't provide more information about it, i will edit the problem to add the function where i try to decode.

Comment: @DanMašek even when  i change to CV_8UC4 nothing change

Comment: @DanMašek   I edited the problem and i added more information, i spent the last two days trying to solve this but nothing work, by the way, the problem maybe in the data i get in the buffer, how do i be sure that my buffer data is correct? is there a way?

Comment: @MikeCAT I added more explanation to the problem. Thank you guys for your help